# Timeline is not running infinitely (JavaFx)

Tags: java, loops, javafx, timeline, infinite

I used to have a simple, timed (more-or-less) infinite loop:

```
while (!canrun) {
    do_stuff(); //simple calculation
    update_gui(); //updates some labels
    Thread.sleep(waittime);
}
```

Which, naturally freezes the JavaFX-Application until it is finished with all calculations (canrun is set to false).

I replaced it with a timeline:

```
    event = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            do_stuff();
            update_gui();
        }
    };
    keyframe = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(waittime), event);
    timeline = new Timeline(Timeline.INDEFINITE, keyframe);
```

do_stuff() looks like this:

```
public void do_stuff() {
    do_the_actual_stuff();
    if (stuff_finished) timeline.stop();
}
```

(waittime is here a number between 1 and 1000 (ms)).
On Buttonclick I start it with timeline.play(), and in do_stuff() I stop it when the calculations are done with timeline.stop().

I also have a function to change the waittime (even when it runs):

```
public void changewaittime() {

    if (!(timeline.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING)) {
        keyframe = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(waittime), event);
        timeline = new Timeline(Timeline.INDEFINITE, keyframe);
    } else {
        timeline.stop();
        keyframe = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(waittime), event);
        timeline = new Timeline(Timeline.INDEFINITE, keyframe);
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

And now my problem is, the Timeline only runs once, and not continuously, it doesn't even enter do_stuff() again, only if I call timeline.play() again. Even directly calling timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE) doesn't help.

Anything I missed?

Edit: I was unable to find my mistake, so I rewrote the complete GUI and now it is working.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved the problem by rewriting my complete GUI and Timeline. Don't know why it didn't work before, but now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

In the Timeline constructor you are setting the frame rate using a constant meant for cycle count.

Use http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setCycleCount(int).